# Strange character from iPhone keyboard

Tags: iphone, unicode, character-encoding, special-characters

I have an iPhone app with thousands of users. Stuff they type goes into my database. I noticed an infrequent crash recently, and tracked it down to a piece of code failing when it had to deal with this character "…" (that's one character, not three dots).

Obviously I need to fix my code to deal with it, but in the meantime. Does anyone know what it is or what key/combination of keys you press on the iPhone keyboard to produce it?

I'm not able to google it, google finds no results. One website told me it was a control character, but "return" is the only control character I can see on the keyboard, and I've tested it, it doesn't produce this.

Oh, and the person who did produce it is in the UK and I imagine has a UK iPhone with a UK English keyboard.

Thanks.

Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called an [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) and, like starblue said, can be entered using Unicode U+2026 OR `&hellip;` as an HTML Entity. If the user entered data containing three dots on a "smart" word processor like MS Word, the ellipsis character usually automatically replaces it. Hope this helps!